# Flink 1.9 won't run program when I use distributed cache, why?

Tags: apache-flink, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, flink-streaming

Problem:

After I run yarn long running session on EMR e.g: flink-yarn-session -d (with additional memory config)

Application is in running state and everything looks fine.
Then when I want to run flink program e.g. flink run -d flink-app.jar --someparams
my flink app seams to be stuck in the sense that it never sends this program for execution on cluster.

I have `Starting execution of program` just standing idle even in detached mode.

(long running session is in running state and it did allocate resources)

So when this started to occur?

I've wanted to integrate some ML models in my flink application and wanted to do that via distributed cache, so I implemented it like so:
`env.registerCachedFile(GENERAL_MODEL_PATH, "general", true);` where GENERAL_MODEL_PATH is loaded via (tried s3 (`s3://mybucket/general.model`) but I made sure ec2 instance has IAM roles to access this bucket and I also tried to load files to hdfs first and then load files by referring to `hdfs://general.model`)

- I load files to hdfs via console: `hdfs dfs -put general.model` (checked files are there)

Then I try to load that model in keyed process function via runtime context like so:

`File fileGeneral = getRuntimeContext().getDistributedCache().getFile("general");`

What is strange to me is when I run exactly same program but skip `env.registerCachedFile` program is accepted and starts execution on the cluster. Otherwise it is never sent for execution? (or something else happens?)

I thought it might need some time to localize all resources and distribute it on worker nodes but this never happens. After some time command fails with this output:

```
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not submit job (JobID: f1592fd2fea2a2457df1a5e1d667a168)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:338)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.DetachedEnvironment.finalizeExecute(DetachedEnvironment.java:77)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:280)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1010)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1083)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1083)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
```

I don't know why it can't submit the job, and how can I investigate this in logs?

Side note:
Looking at application logs in DEBUG mode I never get to this point of flink sending flink-app to execution like it normally happens:

```
2019-11-21 14:31:28,957 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobClient                      - PUT BLOB stream to /127.0.0.1:45922.
2019-11-21 14:31:28,959 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.blob.BlobServerConnection            - Received PUT request for BLOB of job a10c26441b00b0152e380438c4e788d8 with from /127.0.0.1.
```

Heartbeat is however happening.

p.s. I've also tried to add:

`yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb` params but this didn't help.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or why this happens?

> p.p.s. If I load ML models in keyed process function where stream is
>   keyed by user_id, would this produce loading of model for each user?
>   Maybe this is a problem as well?

So not problematic if in open method since it's called once for each parallel instance.

**EDIT**:

Flink 1.8.1 produces the same outcome.

Comment: Hi, what version of Flink are you using? I think you hit a bug, I created a ticket in Flink's jira to track it(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14908). As a workaround you could try: 1) if the model is small, try uploading it from local file system 2) this might still work if you try to submit you program through WebUI as it goes through slightly different path 3) you can try to download the file in open() method of your operator yourself.

Comment: So I'm using Flink 1.9. I've tried with smaller models (say 200kb to test it out, naturally main model is much larger over 200mb), outcome is the same. As for Web UI I would like to keep jenkins setup I've built if possible, and for the open method, I can try that out, but would be surprised if this worked out (p.s. if I load model on keyed process function in open, would this be problematic if key is user_id?), if you have more ideas let me know! Thanks!

Comment: p.s. @DawidWysakowicz local file system looks really inelegant solution as I would have to deploy models to each worker node in cluster, and I imagine this could go wrong in many of ways. (I would prefer localization of resources on a cluster) Does that make sense?

Comment: Note: flink version v1.9.0 is what I'm running.

Comment: First of all I agree all three workarounds I suggested are not perfect. Just wanted to give you some options. What I meant by local file system I meant the file system of the client that submits the job, registerCacheFile should work fine if you register files from the local file system of the client. As I said the files must be small enough so that they fit into HTTP Rest request (sorry I don't know what is the actual size that should work).

Comment: It should not be problematic if you download the file in open of keyed process function. The open method will be called once per each parallel instance not once per key.

Comment: I've resolved it by loading files directly from open method from hdfs dfs. Hopefully this will be resolved so we can use distributed cache.